# Qual o termo certo: "força eletromotriz", "força eletromotora" ou "força eletromotiva"?

Tags: tradução-inglês, termos

Estou fazendo um texto para a faculdade onde eu estou falando do que em inglês é chamado de "electromotive force".

Queria saber qual o termo certo em português:

"força eletromotriz", "força eletromotora" ou "força eletromotiva"?

Sei que pelo termo em inglês, o mais lógico seria escolher "força eletromotiva". Entretanto, o google mostra um número igual de páginas com os três termos.

Outra pergunta: o termo escolhido seria o mesmo para o Brasil ou para Portugal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O termo mais indicado é **Força eletromotriz**.

A coleção de física básica universitária de H. Moysés Nussenzveig (um dos textos mais consagrados de física em português), e a tradução de um dos livros-texto mais adotados nos cursos de engenharia do Brasil (Halliday, Resnick & Walker) usam o termo "força eletromotriz" (para dar apenas dois exemplos), e o termo também é usado no [verbete](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/For%C3%A7a_eletromotriz) correspondente da Wikipedia.

Uma pesquisa pelo termo "força electromotora" revela principalmente páginas em catalão ou claramente escritas por não especialistas. Mas o termo existe, e a Wikipedia [redireciona](https://pt.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=For%C3%A7a_electromotora&redirect=no) o termo para o verbete "força eletromotriz", então "força electromotora" talvez seja por vezes usado em pt-PT - mas certamente não muito frequentemente, porque há menos de 200 *hits* para o termo no Google.

Já a palavra "ele(c)tromotivo" não consta nos dicionários que consultei. Curiosamente, ela é raramente usada, mas aparentemente é mais frequente que "electromotora": tem quase 500 *hits* no Google - mas estes são, em sua maioria, textos de não especialistas ou traduções questionáveis.

[image][image]

Comment: Pois, eu suspeitava que eletromotriz seria o melhor termo. Estranhamente, mesmo se somarmos as páginas existentes para os três termos, encontramos um número pequeno de menções, o que é estranho, pois existem 872 mil ocorrências no google do termo em inglês e essa palavra da física é obrigatória em todo ensino de eletricidade. Muito estranho. Obrigado.

Comment: @SpaceDog Bom ponto, também acho muito estranho - na verdade o (não existente?) "força eletromotiva" tem mais hits que o "força eletromotriz"!

Comment: Este é também o termo que eu usaria para português europeu.

Comment: Claro, força motriz. Nunca seria motora.

Answer (score 1):

> Outra pergunta: o termo escolhido seria o mesmo para o Brasil ou para Portugal?

Em Portugal a grafia usada seria: força electromotriz (com um 'c' na segunda palavra). Se fizer uma pesquisa no google a diferença na grafia vai resultar numa diferença dos resultados.